# Use string of independent variables within the lm function

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have a dataframe with many variables. I want to apply a linear regression to explain the last one with the others. So as I had to much to write I thought about creating a string with the independent variables e.g. Var1 + Var2 +...+ VarK. I achieved it pasting "+" to all column names except for the last one with this code:

```
ExVar <- toString(paste(names(datos)[1:11], "+ ", collapse = ''))
```

I also had to remove the last "+":

```
ExVar <- substr(VarEx, 1, nchar(ExVar)-2)
```

So I copied and pasted the `ExVar` string within the `lm()` function and the result looked like this:

```
m1 <- lm(calidad ~ Var1 + Var 2 +...+ Var K)
```

The question is: Is there any way to use "ExVar" within the `lm()` function as a string, not as a variable, to have a cleaner code?

For better understanding:

If I use this code:

```
m1 <- lm(calidad ~ ExVar)
```

It is interpreting `ExVar` as a independent variable.

Comment: `ExVar <- paste(names(datos)[1:11], collapse = ' + '))` avoids need to remove "+". `lm` can take a string as the formula. Your last line of code isn't working because the whole formula has to be a string, rather than a combination of formula and string. So if your outcome is the variable in, say, the 12th column, you can do: `lm(paste(names(datos)[12], " ~ ", ExVar), data=datos)`. Or, `lm(reformulate(ExVar, names(datos)[12]), data=datos)`. Or you can use a string directly, like `"calidad"` instead of `names(datos)[12]`.

Comment: In my previous comment, the first bit of code has an extra parenthesis. It should be `ExVar <- paste(names(datos)[1:11], collapse = ' + ')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will all produce the same results. I am providing multiple methods because there is are simpler ways of doing what you are asking (see examples 2 and 3) instead of writing the expression as a string.

First, I will generate some example data:

```
n <- 100
p <- 11
dat <- array(rnorm(n*p),c(n,p))

dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
colnames(dat) <- paste0("X",1:p)
```

If you really want to specify the model as a string, this example code will help:

```
ExVar <- toString(paste(names(dat[2:11]), "+ ", collapse = ''))
ExVar <- substr(ExVar, 1, nchar(ExVar)-3)
model1 <- paste("X1 ~ ",ExVar) 
fit1 <- lm(eval(parse(text = model1)),data = dat)
```

Otherwise, note that the 'dot' notation will specify all other variables in the model as predictors.

```
fit2 <- lm(X1 ~ ., data = dat)
```

Or, you can select the predictors and outcome variables by column, if your data is structured as a matrix.

```
dat <- as.matrix(dat)
fit3 <- lm(dat[,1] ~ dat[,-1])
```

All three of these fit objects have the same estimates:

```
fit1
fit2
fit3
```

Comment: Or use `as.formula()`.

Answer (score 2):

if you have a dataframe, and you want to explain the last one using all the rest then you can use the code below:

```
 lm(calidad~.,dat)
```

or you can use

```
 lm(rev(dat))#Only if the last column is your response variable
```

Any of the two above will give you the results needed.

To do it your way:

```
 EXV=as.formula(paste0("calidad~",paste0(names(datos)[-12],collapse = '+')))
 lm(EXV,dat)
```

There is no need to do it this way since the `lm` function itself will do this by using the first code above.